# prolog length of sublist not returning length but returning false?

Tags: list, prolog, range, sublist

so not sure why my code does not work. But i am trying to find the length of a sublist given an lower bound and an upper bound I have this.

```
myrange(_,_,[],0).
myrange(F,L,[H|T],X) :- F <= H,myrange(F,L,T,Y), X is Y+1.
myrange(F,L,[A|T],X) :- L >= A,myrange(F,L,T,Y), X is Y+1.
myrange(F,L,[Y|T],X) :-F>Y, myrange(F,L,T,X).
```

but it returns a false, not sure why.

Comment: `=/2` is not an assignment operator. It's for *unification*. So `X = Y+1` will fail unless `X` is of the form `A+B` (or equivalently, `'+'(A, B)`). Try `X is Y + 1`. There may be other logic issues with your code, but that's the one that immediately jumped out at me.

Comment: Have you tried using a [failure slice](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/failure-slice/info) or using `trace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Smaller or equal" operator in Prolog is `=<`, not `<=`. (The reason for this, as pointed out in the comments, is that `<=` looks too much like an implication arrow and shouldn't be confused with one.)

I don't know about your prolog system, but SWI Prolog gives me a compilation error with your code: "Operator expected", because it doesn't know about the operator `<=`.

After changing the operator, I get a result indeed. However, the predicate as it is is *non-deterministic*, that is you did not say that *only* the first clause is to be applied if it is applicable:

```
?- myrange(7,3,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], L).
L = 6 ;
L = 5 ;
L = 5 ;
L = 4 ;
L = 5 ;
L = 4
```

Consider introducing cuts (`!`) or refining the conditions to get a unique result:

```
myrange(_,_,[],0).
myrange(F,L,[H|T],X) :- F =< H, !, myrange(F,L,T,Y), X is Y+1.
myrange(F,L,[A|T],X) :- L >= A, !, myrange(F,L,T,Y), X is Y+1.
myrange(F,L,[Y|T],X) :- F >  Y, !, myrange(F,L,T,X).

?- myrange(7,3,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], L).
L = 6 ;
false.
```

Comment: You should note in your answer that the reason `=<` is used instead of `<=` is that `<=` looks like an arrow as so to avoid that Prolog uses `=<` so as not to look like an arrow.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks, I edited my answer to point that out. I was aware of it but didn't see it as essential to the answer.